# How can I set the display mode in ACIII?

Tags: assassins-creed-3

With games like CoD MW3/BO2 and BF3, I've been able to change the display mode from the default `fullscreen` to `fullscreen (windowed)`, this allows me to select off the game more easily, which I prefer. I've been unable to find a similar feature for Assassin's Creed III.

Is there an option to do this? 
 If not, why not?

Thanks.

Comment: Why not can't be answered; that's a "Why did the devs do it this way?" sort of question.

Comment: ALT+ENTER or F11 are common shortcuts in windows. whether or not this works is something the game devs would be able to answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately, it is not available, see PC gaming wiki at [http://pcgamingwiki.com/wiki/Assassin's_Creed_III#Video_settings](http://pcgamingwiki.com/wiki/Assassin%27s_Creed_III#Video_settings).

EDIT:
When giving the answer I totally forgot there are some tools that can force fullscreen windowed in games that do not support it. Personally I have never used any of them, so I cannot comment, but http://pcgamingwiki.com/wiki/Borderless_fullscreen_windowed has plenty of info on the subject, as well as a list of tools and links to them.

Comment: @fbueckert thanks for the edit, just read up on inline html :)

Comment: That's annoying but thanks for the answer.

Comment: @Waldfee Markdown!  Takes a bit to get used to, I know.

Comment: this might make me not buy the game, sad.